# CMV Advanced Search Widget

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

In the [README.md](https://github.com/vojvod/CMV_AdvancedSearch_Widget/blob/master/README.md) file for the CMV Advanced Search widget it says to:

> "Copy js/config/search.js file to js/config folder at your CMV
>   installation. Edit file to configure proxy_url and GeometryService_url
>   parameters."

I am just curious if the search.js config file should have more content in it then what is currently included. As of now the following code is stored here:

`define({
    map: true,
    identifyLayerInfos: true,
    proxy_url: 'http://localhost/cmv/proxy/PHP/proxy.php',
    GeometryService_url: 'http://tasks.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer'
});`

It seems there is something missing, is this accurate?